# Sets divs one into another without falling out each other

Tags: html, css

I want to center my divs like in the picture below.

[image]

The container is half of the screen.

```
<div id="continer"  style="width:50%; height:50%; display:inline-block; ">

  <div id="group" style=" width:100%; height:30%; display:inline-block; ">
    <div id="right"  style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div id="left"  style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="group" style=" width:100%; height:30%; display:inline-block; ">
    <div id="right"  style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div id="left"  style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="group" style=" width:100%; height:30%; display:inline-block; ">
    <div id="right"  style="display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div id="left"  style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please show your attempts

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Share the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like that:

```css
.main{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.sub{
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin:10px 0;
}

.inner{
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
}

.inner:nth-child(1){
  flex-grow:1;
}

.inner:nth-child(2){
  flex-grow:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick help. But when I put it on half of screen width and height it look like this. Sub  div do not grow together with container. Can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap it's very simple, check this script. It will be also responsive:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;">

    <h4>
      bootstrap grid view/ column example
    </h4>


    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black;  padding:10px;">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border: 1px solid black;">

        this column is 4/12 wide
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7" style="border: 1px solid red;">

        this column is 7/12 wide
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black;  padding:10px;">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border: 1px solid black;">

        this column is 4/12 wide
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7" style="border: 1px solid red;">

        this column is 7/12 wide
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black;  padding:10px;">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border: 1px solid black;">

        this column is 4/12 wide
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7" style="border: 1px solid red;">

        this column is 7/12 wide
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example similar to your code:

```css
div
{
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:50%;display:table">

<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="width:30%; display: table-cell;"></div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row">
  <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;"></div>
</div>

</div>
```